# Arrow Toggle onclose

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slidetoggle

This has been a multiple-step process(with help), but finally the script to a good point, however, there is one last tidbit I've been running into.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/59kz17d9/4/)

Essentially, this fiddle is is multiple  toggle when open and closed. However, the added feature is that the arrow switches from a rightward position to a downward position when toggled open. Also, when another  is toggled it closes the previous toggle and returns the arrow back to its original position. However on arrow #2 and #3 if clicked the toggled  closes, but the arrow remains in a downward position, how can I get it back to a rightward position if I select that current open toggle as not all users will click another toggle.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     function arrowToggle(that, cName) {
         $(".dtc-one-s, .dtc-two-s, .dtc-three-s").find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');

         if($(cName+"-h").is(":visible"))
             $(that).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
         else
             $(that).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
     }

     // Toggles 1st Hidden Desktop Div
     $(".dtc-s").click(function () {
         arrowToggle(this, ".dtc-one");
         $(".dtc-h").slideToggle(500);
         $(".dtc-two-h").hide(500);
         $(".dtc-three-h").hide(500);
     });
     // Toggles 2nd Hidden Desktop Div
     $(".dtc-two-s").click(function () {
         arrowToggle(this, ".dtc-one");
         $(".dtc-two-h").slideToggle(500);
         $(".dtc-h").hide(500);
         $(".dtc-three-h").hide(500);
         $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
     });
     // Toggles 3rd Hidden Desktop Div
     $(".dtc-three-s").click(function () {
         arrowToggle(this, ".dtc-one");
         $(".dtc-three-h").slideToggle(500);
         $(".dtc-two-h").hide(500);
         $(".dtc-h").hide(500);
         $(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your 2nd and 3rd `click` functions:

```
$(this).find('span').css('transform', 'rotate(90deg)');
```

That line rotates the arrow back to 90deg, which is what you're trying to avoid.

Also, in those same two functions, refer to their class in the `arrowToggle` function instead of `.dtc-one`:

```
 $(".dtc-two-s").click(function () {
   arrowToggle(this, ".dtc-two");
   ...
 });

 $(".dtc-three-s").click(function () {
     arrowToggle(this, ".dtc-three");
   ...
 });
```

Fiddle at **http://jsfiddle.net/o3pyLsug/**